# Running Chrome apps without Chrome installed

Tags: google-chrome, google-hangouts

This may sound paranoid, but I have this thing about installing Google Chrome. I don't trust Google far enough to see my web browsing habits as well. However, I really want to use the desktop Hangouts app that Chrome can run. Is there any way to run Chrome apps without installing Chrome?

Comment: Unless it exists as a separate program you can install, Chrome extensions need to be installed in Chrome itself. I did not find a standalone app for Hangouts.

Comment: You could always just use Chrome for Hangouts, and use another browser to do all of your browsing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Torch, https://www.torchbrowser.com

or

Use Chromium, https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium.

You can run chrome extensions on both of them, without having to be tracked by Google.(Not so sure about Chromium, tho)

Comment: Just FYI, Torch is Windows-only.  Another option would be [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/), which is a great non-Google, Chromium-based browser that's cross-platform and runs Chrome extensions.  Don't know specifically about Hangouts.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there is another Chromium-based browser, Brave.  It is basically Chrome without the tracking, and with a built-in ad blocker.  I am successfully running the Hangouts extension there.

Keep in mind that you are still being tracked by Google if you are using Hangouts.  (I only use Hangouts at work, where the company I work for uses it.)

Answer (score 0):

Do Vivaldi with a User-Agent Switcher, like this:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-and-m/bhchdcejhohfmigjafbampogmaanbfkg?hl=en-US